# How can i get Alexa Slot Value in ASK-SDK lambda function?

Tags: python-2.7, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I want to access the slot value '{cityName}' in my Lambda Function. I am using ASK-SDK. What is the python code or syntax to do so?

[image: My Alexa Console Picture]

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly take a look around and see how to ask a proper question.

Comment: Have you defined the intent slot for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above method is correct but it did not work for me.
Another answer to the above question is as follows:

```
item, is_resolved = util.get_intent_(slots=handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots)
```

and then define function get_intent_ as follows:

```
import random
import six
from ask_sdk_core.handler_input import HandlerInput
from ask_sdk_core.utils import is_request_type

def get_intent_(slots):
    item = []
    resolved_item = None
    for _,slot in six.iteritems(slots):
        if slot.value is not None:
            resolved_item = slot.value

    if resolved_item is not None:
        return resolved_item, True
    else:
        return resolved_item, False
```

This method looks complicated but it is a good practice to define a function and call it.

Answer (score 1):

If the `WeatherApiCallIntent` is triggered with a `CityName` slot value, the request JSON will look like this:

```
"request": {
        "type": "IntentRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx",
        "timestamp": "2018-09-12T13:35:25Z",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "intent": {
            "name": "WeatherApiCallIntent",
            "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
            "slots": {
                "CityName ": {
                    "name": "CityName",
                    "value": "Kochi",
                    ...
```

In you `WeatherApiCallIntent` handler you can use

```
print("Slot: " + intent_request['intent']['slots']['CityName']['value'])
```